# Mysql use parsed column from SELECT in WHERE condition

Tags: mysql

How can I do something like this:

```
SELECT DID, DNumbers, CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(DNumbers, " - ", 1), ", ") AS DNumbers_Parsed
FROM Test
WHERE DNumbers_Parsed LIKE '%, 1,%' AND DNumbers_Parsed LIKE '%, 5,%'
```

This gives an error saying column `DNumbers_Parsed` not found. I know I can just use the same parsing thing for each condition but is it possible to only do it once and then use it in conditions?

Comment: just put it in a subquery

Comment: Your `WHERE` won't match if the `1` or the `5` are at either end of the parsed numbers list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can't use derived fields in a `where` clause, as the value of the derived field MAY not be available yet at the time the `where` filter is being applied (e.g. aggregate function results).

Try using a `HAVING` instead:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
HAVING DNumbers_Parsed LIKE ...
```

`HAVING` is applied just before the results are sent to the client, after all aggregate operations/field value derivations have been completed.

and note that your code above has a typo: `AN DNumbers_....`

Comment: thank you Marc. Does HAVING work the same way as WHERE? is there a speed difference?

Comment: having v.s. where is like requesting a restaurant not include a vegetable you hate on your plate. `where` gets rid of the unwanted data at the kitchen level. `having` is you picking it off the plate after the food arrives at your table.

Answer (score 0):

well the having clause posted by Marc B is a good solution.. even though having is generally slow... another way you could try it is in a sub query so that way the data is already returned from the server.

```
SELECT * 
FROM(
    SELECT DID, DNumbers, CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(DNumbers, " - ", 1), ", ") AS DNumbers_Parsed
    FROM Test
)t
WHERE t.DNumbers_Parsed LIKE '%, 1,%' AN t.DNumbers_Parsed LIKE '%, 5,%'
```